# Remove Extra trailing slash: HAProxy + Ingress Contoller

Tags: kubernetes, url, kubernetes-ingress, haproxy

I have a Kubernetes cluster environment. There is a service running on this environment. I have configured HAProxy on a seperate server and installed ingress controller (using ingress configuration) to handle the request for my service. Everything is working fine except one thing: I must handle extra trailing space in the URL. Example:

> https://myservice.com/car

Above URL is working fine. However following URL are not working, getting 404 error:

> https://myservice.com/car/

> https://myservice.com/car///

I had tried to handle at the ingress level but did not work. I think that It should handle at the HAProxy level. Tried to add a annotation at the ingress level:

> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/preserve-trailing-slash: "false"

How I can handle or remove extra trailing slashes?

Comment: You should handle that in the web server for the service rather than at the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [path-rewrite](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/kubernetes/latest/configuration/ingress/#path-rewrite) to do this.

```
#copy from doc
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:

    haproxy.org/path-rewrite: (.*)/$ \1   # remove last /
```

As the annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/preserve-trailing-slash: "false"` remove the `/` in similar way.

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/rootfs/etc/nginx/lua/lua_ingress.lua#L151-L153

> ```
> if location_config.preserve_trailing_slash == false then
>   if string.byte(request_uri, -1, -1) == string.byte('/') then
>     request_uri = string.sub(request_uri, 1, -2)
> ```